# convert Date time from UTC to IST in report builder connected with Databricks

Tags: reporting-services, databricks

I have a SSRS Report developed with Report builder and I have used Databricks as the datasource.
However I have a UTC date time field to convert it to IST.
I have used

from_utc_timestamp(C.vehicleInTime, 'IST') as VehicleInTime

in the query. But it is not working in the report. It returns an SQL error from the report.
Can anyone help me to convert the datetime field to IST?

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate view and setting that as a datasource?
If I understood you correctly, you are adding the from_utc_timestamp() in SSRS, but probably it had some internal SQL validator that doesn't find this method.

If you define a new view in Databricks, with from_utc_timestamp applied, you could use the new view as a datasource in SSRS and that should work.